# B of a pseudo-group

Tags: homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces

I am thinking about the classifying space construction.

The loop space functor Ω : Grpd₀ ⭢ Grpd sends a space to an internal pseudo group.

Elsewhere I have seen people write BΩX for a based connected CW-complex.

I am trying to think about how the construction of E(ΩX) should go, and then form B(ΩX) as a quotient of it by an action. ΩX is an internal pseudo group; it is associative and unitial up to homotopy.

I can't figure out how to describe a homotopy colimit of a pseudo group which will produce a contractible space. I think it should involve a geometric realization

$\text{coeq}$ $\amalg$ ΩX${}^{n}$ × Δ${}^{m}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\amalg$ ΩX${}^{n}$ × Δ${}^{n}$.

My question is whether this defines a pseudo functor which can play the role of E.

Comment: Is Grpd for you the $(2,1)$-category of groupoids, or the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-groupoids? I am asking because you refer to the objects of it as spaces.

Comment: Also, how exactly do you use the term ''pseudogroup'' here? Do you just mean a higher group, or do you mean the notion as defined here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pseudogroup? The latter doesn't seem to fit with your question, but I have not heard anyone call a higher group a pseudogroup either.

Comment: @DaniëlApol it should consist of η : 1 ⭢ G and μ : G × G ⭢ G which induces a group in the category whose maps are homotopy classes of maps.

Comment: @DaniëlApol evidently there is some material on E₁ in regards to exactly what the classifying space is defined on. It is not defined on all internal groups in the derived category.

Comment: @DaniëlApol I'm trying to understand the homotopy colimit construction which produces a contractible space. Perhaps the information of the B comes from the induced action on this space, and the homotopy colimit / glueing construction itself does not feature the information of the group?

Comment: @Cayley-Hamilton And you're specifically interested in the construction of $E(\Omega X)$ (and consequently $B(\Omega X)$ in case $X$ is a connected groupoid? Or in case $X$ is a connected CW-complex/connected space? Because in these cases, $\Omega X$ will have at least a canonical $\mathbb{E}_1$-group structure (i.e. the structure of a group object in the $\infty$-category of spaces/homotopy types/$\infty$-groupoids/anima), and then the usual construction $BG\simeq \mathrm{hocolim}_{[n]\in\Delta^\mathrm{op}} G^n$ for $\mathbb{E}_1$-groups $G$ applies.